# Sites up or down check with powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

How can I do this script for more then 1 site? I know there is a for each command but can you assist me how can i add this loop for this script?

```
    Begin {
    $webRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://172.20.1.33:81");
}
Process {
    $validStatus = 200, 401

    try {
        $status = $webRequest.GetResponse().StatusCode.value__
    } catch {
        $status = $_.Exception.InnerException.Response.StatusCode.value__
    }
    
    if ($validStatus -contains $status) {
        Write-Host 'Site is up.'
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Site is down.'
    }
}
```

Comment: turn your partial function into an advanced function. then simply send the URIs in as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like part of a function. You could turn into into an [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-5.1), and make the url a [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1), that accepts multiple values and even pipeline input.

```bsh
function Test-Url {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Url,
        [int[]]$ValidStatus = (200, 401)
    )
    process {
        foreach ($item in $Url) {
            $webRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($item)
            try {
                $response = $webRequest.GetResponse()
            }
            catch {
                $response = $_.Exception.InnerException.Response    
            }
            $statusCode = $null
            if ($response) {
                $statusCode = [int]$response.StatusCode
                $response.Close()
            }
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Url = $item
                Online = $validStatus -contains $statusCode
                StatusCode = $statusCode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```bsh
if ((Test-Url "http://172.20.1.33:81").Online) {
    Write-Host 'Site is up.'
} else {
    Write-Host 'Site is down.'
}
```

For multiple sites:

```bsh
Test-Url "http://172.20.1.33:81", "http://172.20.1.34:81"
# or
"http://172.20.1.33:81", "http://172.20.1.34:81" | Test-Url
```

Note that the same is possible using PowerShell's [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1)

```bsh
function Test-Url {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Url,
        [int[]]$ValidStatus = (200, 401)
    )
    process {
        foreach ($item in $Url) {
            $webRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($item)
            try {
                $response = Invoke-WebRequest $item
            }
            catch {
                $response = $_.Exception.Response
            }
            $statusCode = $null
            if ($response) {
                $statusCode = [int]$response.StatusCode
            }
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Url = $item
                Online = $validStatus -contains $statusCode
                StatusCode = $statusCode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for the quick answer ! , i copy and past your code to powershell ISE but nothing happened

Comment: Sorry , maybe I don't understand or don't to something right ..

I can not write here what i write in the screen because it is to much characters 

how can i show you what im trying to run in powershell ?

Comment: You mean this ? 

function Test-Url {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]

Comment: Ok it working !! but for multiple sites it wont work , i wrote 2 url one for working site and one for not , but i still getting 1 massage  " site is up "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224156/discussion-between-simba-and-marsze).

Comment: i wrote you in chat